# Can I run MATLAB MapReduce Framework on hadoop on a Macbook running OS X?

Tags: macos, matlab, hadoop

I am trying to run Mapreduce of Matlab on Hadoop. I am trying to set Environmental Variable in matlab to hadoop installation folder.

```
setenv('HADOOP_HOME', '/usr/local/bin/hadoop')
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Error using parallel.cluster.Hadoop (line 111) 
Unable to recognize '/Users/Hadoop/Documents/hadoop-2.7.2/' as a valid HADOOP installation folder. 
Check that this is the root of your HADOOP installation folder.
```

MATLAB version: R2015b
OS X Version: 10.10.5 OS X Yosemite
Hadoop version: 2.7.2

I installed hadoop using Homebrew

```
brew install hadoop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Hadoop v2, you'll want to set the `HADOOP_PREFIX` or the `MATLAB_HADOOP_INSTALL` environment variable instead of the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable.

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-from-hdfs.html#buh9wha-1)

> - If you work with Hadoop v1 only, set the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable.
> - **If you work with Hadoop v2 only, set the `HADOOP_PREFIX` environment variable.**
> - If you work with both Hadoop v1 and Hadoop v2, or if the `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_PREFIX` environment variables are not set, set the `MATLAB_HADOOP_INSTALL` environment variable.

Also you want to be sure that you are pointing to the *installation folder* and not the executable. So rather than `/usr/local/bin/hadoop` (the executable) it will be something like `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec` (the installation folder).

You will also need to specify the location of Java for hadoop to use. [More information on that here](http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html).

Comment: I did still not working. I tried setting the same Java folders for both MATLAB and Hadoop, still no Luck. It displays the same error.

Comment: @banureddy Can you post the exact code that you're using?

Comment: I found the hadoop version by typing in the terminal

Comment: I found the hadoop home by typing in the terminal

`which hadoop`

I got 

`/usr/local/bin/hadoop`

Then I set the same path in the Matlab as

`setenv('MATLAB_PREFIX', '/usr/local/bin/hadoop');`

and I run
`parallel.cluster.Hadoop;`

Error is

`Error using parallel.cluster.Hadoop (line 111)
Cannot find Hadoop. Set the HADOOP_PREFIX, HADOOP_HOME, or MATLAB_HADOOP_INSTALL environment
variable to a valid Hadoop installation folder and try again.`

Comment: @banureddy see update. You're pointing to the executable and *not* the installation folder.

Comment: I did that too, still the same error,

`setenv('HADOOP_PREFIX', '/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2');`

and

Error:

`Error using parallel.cluster.Hadoop (line 111)
Unable to recognize '/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2' as a valid HADOOP installation folder. Check
that this is the root of your HADOOP installation folder.`

Comment: My Hadoop folder contents are:

/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2:

bin (directory),
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json,
libexec (directory),
LICENSE.txt,
logs (directory),
NOTICE.txt,
README.txt,
sbin (directory)

Comment: @banureddy A few things 1) Try using the `libexec` subfolder of the installation directory instead 2) I would assume that you need to be using MATLAB's java so look into some of the configuration [here](http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I first set the same JAVA_HOME for both Hadoop and MATLAB and set the home path as `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec` and It worked!

Comment: @banureddy Glad that worked. I have updated my answer with the full details.

Comment: @banureddy Please consider marking this as the solution if it solved your problem.